# Assigning SYSDATE to prompt

Tags: sql, oracle, peoplesoft

So I have this line of code in my SQL:

```
AND ((:3 IS NOT NULL
AND A.ADM_CREATION_DT BETWEEN :3 AND SYSDATE)
OR :3 IS NULL
AND :3 = SYSDATE)
```

What I want it to do is that if Prompt 3 or :3 has a value it gets all the value of ADM_CREATION_DT that is in between  the value of :3 and SYSDATE - this works fine. What doesnt work is the part where when :3 is blank it should set the value to SYSDATE which is the current date.

I get the error below:

> Error in running query because of SQL Error, Code=8006, Message=Invalid datatype specified (50,380)

I think it has something to do with assigning SYSDATE to prompt, where their datatype is different.

Anyone who knows how to fix this? Thank you so much.

Full Query provided below:

```
SELECT A.EMPLID, B.NAME, A.ACAD_CAREER, G.STDNT_CAR_NBR, A.ADM_APPL_NBR, A.INSTITUTION, TO_CHAR(A.ADM_CREATION_DT,'YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_CHAR(A.ADM_UPDATED_DT,'YYYY-MM-DD'), A.ADM_APPL_COMPLETE, TO_CHAR(A.ADM_APPL_CMPLT_DT,'YYYY-MM-DD'), D.SRVC_IND_CD, D.SRVC_IND_REASON, E.UM_CTXT_WP_FLAG, E.UM_CTXT_WPPLS_FLAG 
  FROM (PS_ADM_APPL_DATA A LEFT OUTER JOIN  PS_SAD_UC_APPLREC C ON  A.EMPLID = C.EMPLID AND C.INSTITUTION = A.INSTITUTION ), PS_PERSON_NAME B, PS_SRVC_IND_DATA D, PS_UM_CTXT_PERCTXT E, PS_SAD_UC_DEC_MAT F, PS_ADM_APPL_PROG G 
  WHERE (( A.EMPLID = B.EMPLID 
     AND A.EMPLID = D.EMPLID 
     AND C.INSTITUTION = E.INSTITUTION 
     AND C.SAD_UC_APPCODE = E.SAD_UC_APPCODE 
     AND C.SAD_UC_PERS_ID = E.SAD_UC_PERS_ID 
     AND E.EFFDT = 
        (SELECT MAX(E_ED.EFFDT) FROM PS_UM_CTXT_PERCTXT E_ED 
        WHERE E.INSTITUTION = E_ED.INSTITUTION 
          AND E.SAD_UC_APPCODE = E_ED.SAD_UC_APPCODE 
          AND E.SAD_UC_PERS_ID = E_ED.SAD_UC_PERS_ID 
          AND E_ED.EFFDT <= SYSDATE) 
    AND E.EFFSEQ = 
        (SELECT MAX(E_ES.EFFSEQ) FROM PS_UM_CTXT_PERCTXT E_ES 
        WHERE E.INSTITUTION = E_ES.INSTITUTION 
          AND E.SAD_UC_APPCODE = E_ES.SAD_UC_APPCODE 
          AND E.SAD_UC_PERS_ID = E_ES.SAD_UC_PERS_ID 
          AND E.EFFDT = E_ES.EFFDT) 
     AND C.INSTITUTION = F.INSTITUTION 
     AND C.SAD_UC_APPCODE = F.SAD_UC_APPCODE 
     AND C.SAD_UC_PERS_ID = F.SAD_UC_PERS_ID 
     AND A.EMPLID = G.EMPLID 
     AND A.ACAD_CAREER = G.ACAD_CAREER 
     AND A.STDNT_CAR_NBR = G.STDNT_CAR_NBR 
     AND A.ADM_APPL_NBR = G.ADM_APPL_NBR 
     AND G.EFFDT = 
        (SELECT MAX(G_ED.EFFDT) FROM PS_ADM_APPL_PROG G_ED 
        WHERE G.EMPLID = G_ED.EMPLID 
          AND G.ACAD_CAREER = G_ED.ACAD_CAREER 
          AND G.STDNT_CAR_NBR = G_ED.STDNT_CAR_NBR 
          AND G.ADM_APPL_NBR = G_ED.ADM_APPL_NBR 
          AND G.APPL_PROG_NBR = G_ED.APPL_PROG_NBR 
          AND G_ED.EFFDT <= SYSDATE) 
    AND G.EFFSEQ = 
        (SELECT MAX(G_ES.EFFSEQ) FROM PS_ADM_APPL_PROG G_ES 
        WHERE G.EMPLID = G_ES.EMPLID 
          AND G.ACAD_CAREER = G_ES.ACAD_CAREER 
          AND G.STDNT_CAR_NBR = G_ES.STDNT_CAR_NBR 
          AND G.ADM_APPL_NBR = G_ES.ADM_APPL_NBR 
          AND G.APPL_PROG_NBR = G_ES.APPL_PROG_NBR 
          AND G.EFFDT = G_ES.EFFDT) 
     AND 1 = 1 AND  F.SAD_UC_MAT_TEXT <> 'SATISFIED' 
     AND E.UM_CTXT_WP_FLAG = 'Y' 
     AND E.UM_CTXT_WPPLS_FLAG = 'Y' 
     AND D.SRVC_IND_CD = 'MC1' 
     AND D.SRVC_IND_CD = 'MDS' 
     AND A.INSTITUTION = :1 
     AND ( A.ACAD_CAREER = :2 
     OR ' ' = :2) 
     AND 1 = 1 AND ((  A.EMPLID = :4 
OR ' ' = :4 
AND (  A.INSTITUTION = :1 
AND  A.ACAD_CAREER = :2)) ) 
     AND 1 = 1 AND ((TO_DATE(:3,'YYYY-MM-DD') IS NOT NULL
AND  A.ADM_CREATION_DT BETWEEN TO_DATE(:3,'YYYY-MM-DD') AND SYSDATE)
OR TO_DATE(:3,'YYYY-MM-DD') IS NULL
AND TO_DATE(:3,'YYYY-MM-DD') = SYSDATE) ));
```

Comment: Please write full query.Whatever you are trying

Comment: `SYSDATE` is already a `DATE` value. Using `TO_DATE(...)` on a DATE value is useless.

Comment: @SNC: updated to provide full sql.

Comment: You mean when :3 has not been provided, you want all the records till the current date? Is that assumption correct?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, i have update it to remove the to_date but still get the same error.

Comment: This may help.

What I understood:

1) if :3 is not null, then it should populate ADM_CREATION_DT from the :3(entered date and sysdate)

2) But in case if :3 is not null, then ADM_CREATION_DT should set to SYSDATE, am I right? @Link

Answer (score 1):

Based on the assumption (you said it was correct in the question comments) that when the date is :3 is not provided you want all records till the current date, the solution is to simply use a anchor date before which you are guaranteed to never have any records. For e.g. 1-Jan-1900

So the WHERE clause becomes

```
A.ADM_CREATION_DT BETWEEN NVL(:3,TO_DATE('01-01-1900','DD-MM-YYYY')) AND SYSDATE
```

Hope that helps?

Comment: Right. Sorry for that. Didn't want to copy the code to an IDE for a simple answer like this. Removed it now.

Answer (score 0):

This may help.

What I understood:

1) if :3 is not null, then it should populate ADM_CREATION_DT from the :3(entered date and sysdate)

2) But in case if :3 is not null, then ADM_CREATION_DT should set to SYSDATE or less than SYSDATE, If this is the case, then please follow this.

```
 select NVL(A.date1,SYSDATE) dt from dummytab A
 where 
 (TO_DATE(:3,'YYYY-MM-DD') IS NOT NULL
  AND  A.date1 BETWEEN TO_DATE(:3,'YYYY-MM-DD') AND SYSDATE)
   OR (TO_DATE(:3,'YYYY-MM-DD') IS NULL
           AND TO_DATE(A.date1,'YYYY-MM-DD') <=  TO_DATE(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

Or

2) But in case if :3 is not null, then ADM_CREATION_DT should set to SYSDATE, If this is the case, then please follow this.

```
 select NVL(A.date1,SYSDATE) dt from dummytab A
  where 
  (TO_DATE(:3,'YYYY-MM-DD') IS NOT NULL
  AND  A.date1 BETWEEN TO_DATE(:3,'YYYY-MM-DD') AND SYSDATE)
  OR (TO_DATE(:3,'YYYY-MM-DD') IS NULL);
```

Here date1 is your ADM_CREATION_DATE.